# Do <html>, <body> and <head> tags even matter anymore?

Tags: html, web-development, development

Back in the 90's books would always talk about using body and head tags. Do those tags even matter anymore?

I've added scripts and style tags and the browsers accept them without any tags.

Comment: Google won't honor canonical tags unless they are in the `<head>`.

Comment: Simply looking at the HTML spec will tell you they most certainly do.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because web development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use proper HTML, including , , , you can't validate a page, so no easy way to spot problems with the actual page coding. I'm going to guess that invalid HTML also significantly affects SEO, to the extent that matters.